# Left join multiple tables for millions of rows on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, join

I am using PostgreSQL via pgadmin3 on Ubuntu 16.04 with 7.7GiB Memory and 4x.3GHz processor.  My only aim with this database is to merge multiple datasets (tables) and extract the final table.  I am wondering what slows my join operation down the most: Having many rows, merging on multiple columns, or mergng multiple tables.

I have the following tables:

```
combinations (121M rows)
----
source | target | year
bigint | bigint | smallint

coauthorships
----
source | target | year
bigint | bigint | smallint

adjacencies
----
source | target | year     | auth_first_order | auth_second_order | com_first_order | com_second_order
bigint | bigint | smallint | double           | double            | double          | double
```

Eventually there will be more tables.  Each row in each table is uniquely identified by `(source,target,year)`. All tables have non-clustered indices on `(source, target, year)`

My initial idea was to construct a view and export the view to disk. This is the definition of view `master`:

```
SELECT comb.source,
 comb.target,
 comb.year,
 coauth.publications,
 adj.auth_first_order,
 adj.auth_second_order,
 adj.com_first_order,
 adj.com_second_order
FROM combinations comb
 LEFT JOIN coauthorships coauth ON comb.source = coauth.source AND comb.target = coauth.target AND comb.year = coauth.year
 LEFT JOIN adjacencies adj ON comb.source = adj.source AND comb.target = adj.target AND comb.year = adj.year;
```

Then I proceeded to export the view like so:

```
psql -U postgres -d department-networks -c "COPY master TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" > ~/master.csv
```

How can I improve the merge design? I have some freedom over the table look like. Given that the tables are not indexed, which method should I use? From [pgadmin's help page](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/index_dialog.html) it looks like both hash and GiST seem appropriate. Should I merge the keys so that I don't merge on multiple columns but just one? Should I join some tables separately so that in the end I only merge two tables? Should I not use postgres at all? I'm grateful for any help in this regard.

EDIT:

Here is the query plan:

```
"Merge Left Join  (cost=2615359.20..10115676.76 rows=146636992 width=52)"
"  Merge Cond: ((comb.source = adj.source) AND (comb.target = adj.target) AND (comb.year = adj.year))"
"  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2048532.06..8406982.78 rows=146636992 width=20)"
"        Merge Cond: ((comb.source = coauth.source) AND (comb.target = coauth.target) AND (comb.year = coauth.year))"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using combinations_source_target_year_idx on combinations comb  (cost=0.57..5107371.45 rows=146636992 width=18)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=2047466.59..2106034.64 rows=11713611 width=20)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=2047466.59..2076750.61 rows=11713611 width=20)"
"                    Sort Key: coauth.source, coauth.target, coauth.year"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on coauthorships coauth  (cost=0.00..191745.11 rows=11713611 width=20)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=566827.14..581496.20 rows=2933811 width=50)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=566827.14..574161.67 rows=2933811 width=50)"
"              Sort Key: adj.source, adj.target, adj.year"
"              ->  Seq Scan on adjacencies adj  (cost=0.00..51115.11 rows=2933811 width=50)"
```

Comment: Please consider reading the [postgres-performance tag wiki](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Comment: Regarding your first question, can you please be more speific? What do you mean by queries? Except the the view definition I don't have any other query.

Comment: @RDFozz: It will be repeated but in total not more than say 10 times. `combinations` contains just those three columns and I want non-matching rows to be emtpy. Hence the left join.

Comment: @MERose - And, are you *absolutely* certain that `source`, `target` and `year` are unique? You indicated in comments to Evan Carroll's answer that `coauthorships` and `adjacencies` do have indexes on those three columns, but not `combinations`; are these *unique* indexes? If you're relying on them to be, I'd enforce the assumption. For `combinations`, the index should be the clustered primary key - if not appropriate as a primary key for the others, then you should at least have the three columns as a unique constraint/index.

Comment: Also - is `coauth` a table in its own right? If not, then you've got it listed twice in your table description in the question.

Comment: @RDFozz: `(source,target,year)` are unique and combinations have just been indexed. How can I cluster the index? I tried `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ...` but it's not accepted. `coauthorships` is a column on its own and `coauth` an alias. Thanks for pointint that out, question edited.

Comment: Command is `CLUSTER <table> USING <index>`; however, unlike other platforms, PostgreSQL simply orders the data in the table now - new data is simple added to the end of the table, without reference to the index. Sorry, PostgreSQL isn't my "primary language". If the tables are static for a while, then doing this could still be helpful after each set of updates. Unique indexes are key, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @EvanCarroll: Good point, I wanted to add this as question. The tables are not indexed as I don't know which method to use. Question edited. – MERose 16 secs ago

**Red flag.** Stop your query. Add your indexes. Rerun it. Assuming you have no indexes, add these and then paste the result of `\d table` for coauthorships and adjacencies`.

```
CREATE INDEX ON combinations ( source, target, year );
CREATE INDEX ON adjacencies ( source, target, year );
CREATE INDEX ON coauthorships ( source, target, year );
VACUUM ANALYZE combinations;
VACUUM ANALYZE adjacencies;
VACUUM ANALYZE coauthorships;
```

Also why are you using bigint if you only have millions of rows?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69826/discussion-on-answer-by-evan-carroll-left-join-multiple-tables-for-millions-of-r).